# string within string for Folder location?

Tags: java, string

java beginner here!!

i have a program that can create numerous folders on desktop.
The folder that is created, the name is stored as a string.

my question is:
when using a file writer, how can i pass this string holding the "folder name" just created into the string showing the folder location that is passed to the file writer?

example

```
    String folderpath = System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Desktop\\"+"textfile.txt"+"";
```

passes the location of "desktop" and creates a file there called textfile.txt

i require the textfile.txt to be created into the folder i have created.

doing this in sting: "\Desktop\aFolder\"  wont work, as i will create multiple folders with different names.

i am hoping as i store the name of the folder i just created, i can pass that into this string somehow?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
String dynamicFoldarName="some-folder-name"; // set it programmatically 
String parentPath =System.getProperty("user.home") + File.separator+"Desktop";
String childPath = dynamicFoldarName;
String fileName= "textfile.txt";
String folderpath = parentPath+ File.separator+childPath+File.separator+fileName;
```